# throw exception when files doesn't exist in GCS using apache beam sdk 2.2

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, apache-beam

In version 2.1 of apache beam, when a dataflow does not find the files in GCS of google cloud platform, it throws a FileNotFound exception and stops the execution.

since version 2.2 even if the dataflow does not find the files, it continues the execution.

is there a simple way to stop the dataflow when the files do not exist in GCS even using version 2.2 of apache beam ?

Comment: That's weird. Can you share a snap of your pipeline where file did not exist in GCS and the filename requested?

Comment: problem is resolved in version 2.6 of apache beam sdk. yes that's weird !

Answer (score 1):

problem is resolved in version 2.6 of apache beam. 
now if DataFlow doesn't find file it throw exception.